# fgets() crashes my program

Tags: c, fgets

I'm a newbie in C programming. I'm trying to open a file (juanjo2.klb), its a binary file I've created with the same program, that I'm going to show here. The thing is that I'm trying to use the fprintf() function to print a string to the file and then, use fgets() to write the string into the 'cad' string, and use the function printf() to print to the screen the string I've read from file.

When I run the program, the program crashes and Windows (Windows 7) gives me a message box saying that my program stopped working and it's finding a solution to the problem. So I really don't know what I'm doing wrong becasue I think I'm using the functions correctly. I need your help. Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAXCHARS 20

int main()
{
    char cad[MAXCHARS];
    FILE *pf;
    char *nombre = "\\juanjo2.klb";
    if(pf = fopen(nombre, "a+b") == NULL)
    {
       printf("Error opening file\n");
       exit(-1);
    }

    fprintf(pf, "%s", "Hola como estas");

    while(feof(pf) == 0)
    {
        fgets(cad, 13, pf);
        printf("%s", cad);//Here I print the string to the screen.
    }

    fclose(pf); //Closing file.

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

}

I'm using the Codeblocks IDE 10.05. Thank's for your help.

Comment: You can't print binary data with %s.  For one thing, it might not be null terminated.

Comment: Check the return value of `fgets` before using `cad`.

Comment: You are opening the file for appending in binary mode, and then you are trying to read from it.

Comment: Don't use feof() this way. It does not do what you expect.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: `fgets` will append a null terminator to the data it has read, that is not a problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That's not a problem either.

Comment: `fgets` is *not* you friend. Really. Consider `getline` and similar tools instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
if((pf = fopen(nombre, "a+b")) == NULL)
```

That's a classic.

Answer (score 1):

```
...

int main()
{
    .
    .
    .

    if(pf = fopen(nombre, "a+b") == NULL)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As pointed out by @wildplasser's answer (+1) your first problem is in the line above.

---

This should be:

```
    if((pf = fopen(nombre, "a+b")) == NULL)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Assigns the FILE * to pf and THEN checks if it's NULL

---

The way you have it originally, namely

```
   if(pf = fopen(nombre, "a+b") == NULL) /* wrong */
```

you are setting pf to be the result of `fopen(nombre, "a+b") == NULL which will be either 0 if the boolean statement (==) is FALSE or !0 (usually 1) if it is true.  So pf has the result of boolean and NOT the actual file pointer.  This also causes issues with the if of course because it is now looking at pf.

```
  pf = fopen(nomber, "a+b") == NULL; /* here to clarify == happens before = */

  if ( pf ) /* i.e. pf != 0 */
```